# What is the formula to calculate repeatability score for feature detector-descriptors

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, feature-extraction, feature-detection

With reference to the paper "Performance Evaluation of Feature Detectors and Descriptors Beyond the Visible", there is a paragraph that explains how the repeatability score is calculated, and it stated that (pg 7):

repeatability = number of correspondences / number of features detected in one of the images

Could I find out what correspondences actually mean here?

Does it refer to the number of feature matches after applying matching algorithms such as BFMatcher to two sets of detected features?

I got abit confused as there were two graphs in the paper side by side, and they were "num of matches against different rotations" and "num of correspondence against different rotations" (pg 15).

URL to the paper: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/323007326_Performance_Evaluation_of_Feature_Detectors_and_Descriptors_Beyond_the_Visible

Comment: related: https://forum.opencv.org/t/using-evaluatefeaturedetector-getrecall-and-computerecallprecisioncurve-in-python/6675

Comment: and perhaps this question is a better fit for a different site among https://stackexchange.com/sites